# cannot connect to Oracle database server; error regarding SQL Server

Tags: .net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

When I want to connect my Oracle database server in Visual Studio 2010, 1 hour ago there is no error but now I'm getting this error.

[image]

My web.config has a connection string:

```
<add name="ora" connectionString="Data Source=SCN;User id=********;Password=**********" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

My **TNSNAMES.ORA**;

```
SCN=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=10.10.10.18)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SID=SCN)
    )
  )
```

I'm getting this strange error.

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: that error is screaming about "SQL Server" can you post the using statements as well as the connection/command objects creations

Comment: How have you declared myConnection? I must say that I find it odd that the error message implies that it is attempting to connect to SQL Server when you seem to want to be connecting to Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Oracle connection string and .ora file aren't related to the connection error to SQL Server.

Your error is :

> ...establishing a connection to SQL Server....

Ensure your `myConnection` has the correct connection string as you'd expect. Something like this:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ora"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine which connection string are you using and which connection data type. Try to output the content of:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString
```

and

```
myConnection.GetType().ToString()
```

also click on "Copy exception detail to the clipboard" to get more useful the real type of `myConnection`